# Write Parcelable for ArrayList<String []> in android?

Tags: android, arraylist, parcelable, arrays

I just created model with String array and array list of string array.Like this

```
public class LookUpModel implements Parcelable
{
    private String [] lookup_header;
    private ArrayList<String []> loookup_values;

 public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

            dest.writeStringArray(getLookup_header());

        };

}
```

I have implemented parcelbale then write for String [] but how to do for the `ArrayList<String []>` and  that values need to pass to another activity.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://androidhub.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/android-intents-for-passing-data-between-activities-part-3/. check this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `dest.writeStringList(loookup_values);` 
Refer to the following 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeStringList(java.util.List)
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks friend but it will write list<Sting> not an ArrayList<String[]>  @S.A.Norton Stanley

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I could think about is the following:

```
public static final class LookUpModel implements Parcelable {
    private String [] lookup_header;
    private ArrayList<String []> lookup_values;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return hashCode();
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeStringArray(lookup_header);

        dest.writeInt(lookup_values.size());

        for (String[] array : lookup_values) {
            dest.writeStringArray(array);
        }
    };

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<LookUpModel> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<LookUpModel>() {
        public LookUpModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new LookUpModel(in);
        }

        public LookUpModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new LookUpModel[size];
        }
    };

    /**
     * Specific constructor for Parcelable support
     * @param in
     */
    private LookUpModel(Parcel in) {
        in.readStringArray(lookup_header);

        final int arraysCount = in.readInt();

        lookup_values = new ArrayList<String[]>(arraysCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < arraysCount; i++) {
            lookup_values.add(in.createStringArray());
        }
    }
}
```