# Parcelable implementation with field ArrayList<String[]>

Tags: java, android, parcelable

Currently I use writeList() and readList(), my program is not stable, don't know if this is the problem. This does work at least most times. Same question was asked before here [Write Parcelable for ArrayList<String []> in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417623/write-parcelable-for-arrayliststring-in-android), but no satisfactory answer was provided.

```
public static final class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
private ArrayList<String []> t_values;

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return hashCode();
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeList(t_values);

};

private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {

    t_values = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    t_values.readList(in);
}
.....
}
```

Comment: This must work : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17417999/1112882

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but does writeList()/readList() look correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me, what the problem? Have you tried it?

Comment: My application crashes sometimes when it wakes up. Not sure if it's because of this or something else.

Comment: For God's sake check your logcat and post your exception instead of just blindly guessing the part of code that might be buggy. How can someone code without logcat?

Comment: I do use logcat. My program calls native code, if I try to load many other applications to let the system put my program into sleep, then wake it up, memory allocated by the native code before the sleep becomes inaccessible (debugger says it's unaccessible, also the native code would cause segmentation fault if I try to access it), the memory is not free'd by me (I put a __android_log_write() into the freeing code to catch it). This is quite strange, so I look into all kinds possibilities.